# React Hooks Prevent Button to re-render when typing in field

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, rerender

Editing my question to make it a bit clearer

I don’t want the button to re-rendering when I type in the field and when I click on the button I want to update a state object

Here I have 2 components

```
const mainState = {
  title: '',
};

const ButtonComponent = ({ confirmTitleName }) => {
  return (
    <>
      <TestReRender label={'Button Container'}/>
      <button style={{backgroundColor: 'red', outline: 'none'}} onClick={() => confirmTitleName('confirmTitleName >>>')}>CLICK ME</button>
    </>
  )
};

const InputComponent = ({ state, setState }) => {
  return (
    <>
      <TestReRender label={'Input Container'}/>
      <input
        type="text"
        value={state}
        onChange={(e) => setState(e.target.value)}
      />
    </>
  )
};
```

Then I have created a component made up of the previous two

```
const InputAndButtonComponent = memo(({ confirmTitleName }) => {
  const [state, setState] = useState('');


  const Btn = () => <ButtonComponent confirmTitleName={() => confirmTitleName(state)}/>;

  return (
    <>
      <InputComponent state={state} setState={setState} />
      <Btn />
    </>
  )
});
```

The last component `InputAndButtonComponent` is then imported in the Main component

```
const Main = () => {
  const [confirmTitle, setConfirmTitle] = useState(mainState);

  const confirmTitleName = useCallback((value) => {
    setConfirmTitle((prevState) => (
      {
        ...prevState,
        title: value
      }
    ))
  }, []);

  return (
    <main className={styles.CreateWorkoutContainer}>
      <>
        <TestReRender label={'Main Container'}/>
        <div>
          <InputAndButtonComponent confirmTitleName={confirmTitleName} />
        </div>
      </>
    </main>
  )
};
```

Now the problem is that when I write the component `InputAndButtonComponent` as follow it re-renders when I type in the input field

```
const InputAndButtonComponent = memo(({ confirmTitleName }) => {
  const [state, setState] = useState('');

  return (
    <>
      <InputComponent state={state} setState={setState} />

      // This re-renders when typing
      <ButtonComponent confirmTitleName={() => confirmTitleName(state)}/>;
    </>
  )
});
```

But the original version does not re-render when I type in the field

```
const InputAndButtonComponent = memo(({ confirmTitleName }) => {
  const [state, setState] = useState('');


  // This makes the <Btn /> below not re-rendering. I don't understand why
  const Btn = () => <ButtonComponent confirmTitleName={() => confirmTitleName(state)}/>;

  return (
    <>
      <InputComponent state={state} setState={setState} />

      // This does not re-render
      <Btn />
    </>
  )
});
```

Comment: You should use in that case an uncontrolled input instead of a controlled one.

Comment: Your arrow function is being recreated on every render `() => confirmTitleName(state)`. That's why your button is re-rendering.